# sql query to fix phone number problem in table

Tags: asp.net, sql, regex, sql-server-2005

I have a table which contains a phone number column. There is no restrictions on how to enter the phone numbers. Currently the phone numbers are in the following format

```
123-456-7890
(123)-456-7890
1234567890
```

I would like to update the table and bring all phone numbers in 123-456-7890 format. I have over 20k records. Can I do that using SQL Query or I have to use regular expression in ASP or PHP?

Edit: Note **best answer** is for modified question, with phone number (123)-456-78790 **changed to** (123)456-7890

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they are strictly in one of those 3 formats, you can do it in SQL easy enough by using `SUBSTRING` and testing the `LEN` of each item.

If there are other formats, I'd suggest doing this in a language that is better at text-manipulation, such as .net.

**Edit to add:**

Given your comment that it'll only be those 3 formats for now, you can do this:

```
declare @t table (x varchar(20))
insert into @t 
select '123-456-7890'
union select '(123)456-7890'
union select '1234567890'

select 
    case 
      when len(x) = 10 then 
        substring(x, 1, 3) + '-' + substring(x, 4, 3) + '-' + substring(x, 7, 4)
      when len(x) = 13 then
        substring(x, 2, 3) + '-' + substring(x, 6, 8)
      else x
    end
from @t
```

Comment: worked great but I changed `(123)-456-7890` to `(123)456-7890`. How to I modify the code to take care of it

Comment: Just for anyone who refers to this in the future, you neglected to change the example '(123)-456-7890' to '(123)456-7890' when you revised the query.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

First replace the parentheses and hyphens, then add them back in.

```
DECLARE @Number varchar(25)
SELECT @Number = '(123)-456-7890'

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Number, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), 1, 3) 
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Number, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), 4, 3)  
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Number, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), 7, 4)
```

**Note**
You could create a scalar function to replace all the hyphens and parentheses... It would be more readable then:

```
DECLARE @Number varchar(25)
SELECT @Number = '(123)-456-7890'

SELECT SUBSTRING(StripCharacters(@Number), 1, 3) 
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(StripCharacters(@Number), 4, 3)  
    + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(StripCharacters(@Number), 7, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a great example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLPhoneNumbersPart_2.aspx?display=Print):
Shows how to create User Defined Functions, custom formatting function for telephone numbers in TSQL

Comment: Unqualified or -explained links are not very helpful.

Comment: The link is hardly unqualified and I added comments to explaining what you will find :)

Answer (score 1):

Succinct and without temp tables:

```
UPDATE Phones 
 SET phone = 
SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone,'-',''),')',''),'(',''),1,3) + '-'
+ SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone,'-',''),')',''),'(',''),4,3) + '-'
+ SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone,'-',''),')',''),'(',''),7,4)
```

Comment: Quick and dirty... and ugly :P

Answer (score 0):

I would load every phone number and strip them.

So remove all periods, commas, hyphens, - basically anything that isn't a number.

Then reinsert them in the format you're looking for.

you can do this through a query, or server side language.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 20K records then just go with whatever is easier for you. Personally, I would pull all the data and then reinsert it using a server side language. PHP, ASP, or SQL it doesn't really matter if this is a one time thing. Just be sure to set up some formatting restrictions on new inserts though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
  phonenumber VARCHAR(15)
)

INSERT INTO #temp 
        ( phonenumber )
VALUES  ( '555-578-5899'

 INSERT INTO    #temp
            ( phonenumber )
 VALUES  ( '(555)-896-3269'  )

INSERT INTO #temp
        ( phonenumber )
VALUES  ( '123-456-2129')


update #temp
set phonenumber=replace(phonenumber,'(','')
update #temp
set phonenumber=replace(phonenumber,')','')
update #temp
set phonenumber=replace(phonenumber,'-','')

 -- That will eliminate all (,- and ) from the table

update #temp
set phonenumber=left(phonenumber,3)+'-'+substring(phonenumber,4,3)
+'-'+right(phonenumber,4) 

 SELECT * FROM #temp

 DROP TABLE #temp
```